# go to ABC Park vs get to ABC Park

Tags: difference

(1) How do you go to ABC Park?

(2) How do you get to ABC Park?

Can I use "go to" and "get to" interchangeably in these questions?

If not, how do you know when to say which one?

Answer (score 1):

The most typical way that people ask for directions is "how do you get to...", so number (2) sounds more natural if you're asking for general directions.  North Americans learn this from a very early age with the [theme song](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/2009/11/05/sesame-street-lyrics-the_n_347200.html) to the TV show "Sesame Street", which has the refrain

> Can you tell me how to get,
>
> How to get to Sesame Street?

Your sentence (1) could mean the exact same thing, but it sounds less idiomatic.  The active word **go** makes it sound a bit like I'm asking the route that **you specifically** use to travel to the park (maybe I already know how to get there, but I've learned that you have a short-cut).  Usually the surrounding context would make it clear if this is what is being asked, and the questioner might put extra stress the word **you** in a spoken question.

Comment: It might help to add that "how do you go to" could be asking about conveyance, e.g. by car vs by bus.

Comment: Your detailed explanation has helped me understand the difference between the two questions. I really appreciate your help.